# Calling a set $A$ odd versus stating $|A|$ is odd

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology

I'm trying to write a formal paper to submit to a journal. If $A$ is a finite set with an even (resp. odd) number of elements is it ok to write "Let $A$ be an even (resp. odd) set such that ..."  rather than "Let $A$ be a set such that $|A|$ is even (resp. odd)...". Is one more common/preferable?

Comment: "even set" is not standard.  What's wrong with "$A$ is a set of even order?"

Comment: "Even set" might make the reader think it's a set of even numbers, similarly for "odd".

Comment: If you insist on using that (nonstandard) terminology, at least introduce it and call attention to it. But unless there is a compelling reason to use this terminology, I'd stick with something more standard.